# Align content on left edge of page

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am having trouble with placement. I want to make my 's set as links eventually, but for aesthetic purposes I want my border lines to start at the left edge of the page and go to whole width of the page. Instead the content is lined up about 5-10px right of the left edge, and when my content is set to 100% width it makes my page have a horizontal scroll bar. I want it just to fit on one page with no scroll bars. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<input id="searchbar" type="search" placeholder="search" />

<div id="search" class="accommodation">Accomodation<img class="arrowtwo" src="../images/arrow.png" alt="accommodation"/>
<
/div>

<div id="search" class="activities">Activities<img class="arrowtwo" src="../images/arrow.png" alt="activities"/>
</div>

<div id="search" class="facilities">Facilities<img class="arrowtwo" src="../images/arrow.png" alt="facilities"/>
</div>

<div id="search" class="food">Food<img class="arrowtwo" src="../images/arrow.png" alt="food"/>
</div>

<div id="search" class="health">Health<img class="arrowtwo" src="../images/arrow.png" alt="health"/>
</div>

<div id="search" class="services">Services<img class="arrowtwo" src="../images/arrow.png" alt="services"/>
</div>

<div id="search" class="sights">Sights<img class="arrowtwo" src="../images/arrow.png" alt="sights"/>
</div>

<div id="search" class="transportation">Transportation<img class="arrowtwo" src="../images/arrow.png" alt="transportation"/>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body.search{background-color: rgb(84,163,188);
display:block;
width:100%;
}

img.arrowtwo{
width:40px;
height:7px;
margin-right: 10px;
float:right;
}

#search{
border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #000000;
border-collapse:collapse;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
width:100%;
position:relative;
left:0px;

}
```

Comment: From your html code, i cannot see any class call search.

Comment: Also, you have multiple ids with the same name. ids are by nature supposed to be unique. you can swap the class names with the ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the scrollbars because the div will now a width of 100% plus padding. An idea would be to wrap your current html inside another div and set it's width to be 100% then add the padding to form inside your new div:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input id="searchbar" type="search" placeholder="search" />
  // the rest of your form here ....
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped alot!